# How to modify string element of a NSArray using fast enumeration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsarray

Can anyone pls suggest how to string element of an NSArray using fast enumeration. Its very easy to do the same with normal for loop. Below code works fine

```
_tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F", nil];

NSUInteger i=0;
for (; i<[_tempArray count]; i++) {
     if ([[_tempArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
            [_tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"a"];
      }
}
```

I want to do the same as above code does with fast enumeration. I tried the below code **but it gives *****Error**: **Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x610000043090> was mutated while being enumerated.********, which means it is not possible to modify the collection while enumerating it. Can anyone suggest any way to achieve it.**

```
NSUInteger j=0;
    for (NSString *temp in _tempArray) {
        if ([temp isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
            [_tempArray replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:@"a"];
        }
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code that works? What is your end goal?

Comment: maybe you want to use `lowercaseString`

Comment: @Wain because its faster than normal for loop

Comment: And how big is your iteration (and how small the work done on each iteration) that you need to worry about it? You have profiled to prove that this is a bottleneck for you?

Comment: This is pre-mature optimization--don't do it. Write your code in the cleanest, most simple, most clear way to understand that is possible. Then if there are problems use the profiler tools to find the real performance issues and fix them.

Comment: There are hardly any implementations of "fast enumeration", in any language, that allow a collection to be mutated while it's being enumerated.  And the specs clearly state that you cannot in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to modify string element of a NSArray using fast enumeration?

Don't. You are not supposed to modify the array during enumeration. It's not an arbitrary restriction -- doing so may result in logical errors.

If you want to modify/transform an array, then use an explicitly indexed for loop instead.

Comment: *You are not supposed to modify array elements during enumeration.* wrong. you can change any object in an array during enumeration, as long as you don't change the array itself. and you should not change an array during looping as-well, as the same consequences may arise.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Actually, I meant that the array's structure should not be modified, my wording was confusing, fixed. As to your second comment: no, if you keep explicit indices and you kepp track of the array size, and take care of the indices being used properly (things that you can't do with fast enumeration), then it's perfectly fine to modify the array. How else would you implement a sorting algortithm then, for example?

Comment: problems can arise in threaded environments. I'd enumerate a copy, change there original. one variation of this: reverse enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You can tighten up the code with the array indexing syntax:

```
for (int i=0; i<_tempArray.count; i++) {
    if ([_tempArray[i] isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        _tempArray[i] = @"a";
    }
}
```